# Difference in meaning between did you speak to... and have you spoken to...?

Tags: meaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do the tenses in English correspond temporally to one another?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another)

What's the difference in meaning between "Did you speak to the landlord this morning?" and "Have you spoken to the landlord this morning?"

Answer (score 6):

It has been pointed out in a few grammar books that the *present perfective* describes a past event with *present relevance*. Whatever that is and whether there is a difference depends on the context.

From Practical English Usage, Swan, 3rd ed.:

> The difference between the present perfect and the simple past is not
>   always very clear-cut. It often depends on our ‘focus’: are we
>   thinking mostly about the present relevance of a past event, or about
>   the past details? In some cases both present perfect and past are
>   possible with little difference of meaning.

A nice explanation of *present relevance*, from Cruse, 2000:

> Consider the difference between the following:
>
> (39)    John read the book.
>
> (40)    John has read the book.
>
> Both indicate that John’s reading of the book occurred in the past.
>   But the first sentence directs our attention into the past, to the
>   specific time when the event occurred; the second sentence, on the
>   other hand, directs our attention towards John’s present state, or at
>   least at aspects of it which are attributable to his having read the
>   book at some (indeterminate) time in the past. This is the essence of
>   the perfect: present relevance of past events.

Answer (score 2):

If it is still *this morning*, then it needs to be the present perfect:

- Have you spoken to the landlord this morning?

because *this morning* is an expression of *unfinished time* and implies the possibility that you still might speak to the landlord.

If, on the other hand, it is no longer *this morning* (it is afternoon or evening of the same day), then it has to be the past simple:

- Did you speak to the landlord this morning?

because *this morning* is now an expression of *finished time*.

Comment: @Shoe- Americans wouldn't really bother with this subtle difference in day today conversation. They would simply go with *did* in most cases:)

Comment: @Noah, You are right that Americans are more likely to use the past simple with expressions of unfinished time, whereas Britons would prefer the present perfect (*Did you eat yet? / Have you eaten yet?*). But I would be interested to hear from an American whether your assertion is correct that they would use the past simple *in most cases* in this particular context - particularly if it is still early in the morning when the question is asked.

Comment: I'd go so far as to say that *Did you eat yet?* is ungrammatical in British English, which is probably because *yet* indicates unfinished time.